# Pine Language - Undeclared Identifier Error

Tags: pine-script, undeclared-identifier

What is wrong with this code? I'm getting an undeclared identifier error. Don't see why

```
// This is a simple moving average cross-over strategy
//@version=3
strategy("Crossover")

// Buy rule
entryLong = crossover(sma(10), sma(20))
if (entryLong)
    strategy.entry("MyLong", strategy.long, qty=1, limit=10, stop=5)

// Sell rule
entryShort = crossunder(sma(10), sma(20))
if entryShort
    strategy.entry("MyShort", strategy.short, qty=1, limit=10, stop=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the version 5 of pinescript as version 3 is clearly obsolete and generate errors hard to spot.
Here is your code in the version 5 :

```
//@version=5
strategy("Crossover")

// Buy rule
entryLong = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close,10), ta.sma(close,20))
if (entryLong)
    strategy.entry("MyLong", strategy.long, qty=1, limit=10, stop=5)

// Sell rule
entryShort = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close,10), ta.sma(close,20))
if entryShort
    strategy.entry("MyShort", strategy.short, qty=1, limit=10, stop=5)
```

Comment: Thank you! It compiles now but when applied to the chart for the testing it says "no data". Hence, there still is some issue with the code. I can't figure out why...

Comment: @SulkhanMetreveli if this answer resolde your 'undeclared identifier' error, please accept the answer. If you have another problem, please ask a new question, we will be able to help you this way